# What are the major differences between Apple Watch versions?

Tags: hardware, apple-watch

With all the different versions of the Apple Watch, what are the major differences between them? Apple no longer lists tech differences between hardware they don't sell, so it's difficult to find the details in one place.

Comment: Discussion about why this question was closed: https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/why-was-this-question-closed-for-being-off-topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are the **additions** to each generational release (each series takes on features from the previous generation):

### Series

**Series 0** (April 2015)

- First ever release
- 450 nits screen

**Series 1** (September 2016)

- 100% faster than Series 0

**Series 2** (September 2016)

- 100% faster than Series 0 (ie. same speed as S1)
- Brighter screen (1000 nits)
- GPS
- 50m water resistance

**Series 3** (September 2017)

- 70% faster than Series 1/2
- Barometric altimeter (altitude measurement)
- Optional LTE (Cellular service without phone)

**Series 4** (September 2018)

- 100% faster than Series 3
- Expanded screen size
- ECG (electrocardiogram) feature
- Fall detection (if you fall it will alert authorities)
- Health monitoring (notice of potential heart problems)

**Series 5** (September 2019)

- Same speed as Series 4
- Always-on display
- Compass

**Series 6** (September 2020)

- 20% faster than Series 4/5
- Blood oxygen sensor
- Brighter screen when wrist is down

**Series 7** (September 2021)

- Same speed as Series 6
- Smaller screen borders
- Tougher screen
- Fast charging ability

**Series 8** (September 2022)

- Same speed as Series 6/7
- Body temperature-sensor (cycle tracking)
- Vehicle crash detection

**Series 9** (September 2023)

- "Up to" 60% faster than Series 6/7/8
- Brighter screen (2000 nits)
- "Double tap" gesture using your fingers
- Fully carbon neutral (from manufacture to delivery to lifetime of use)

### SE

**SE** (September 2020)

- Same as Apple Watch Series 5... minus always-on display

**SE 2** (September 2022)

- 20% faster
- Vehicle crash detection

### Ultra

**Ultra** (September 2022)

- Larger screen than Series
- Bigger battery life than Series (36 hours)
- Tougher case than Series
- 100m water resistance
- New "Action" button
- Depth gauge
- Water temperature sensor
- and many more features...

**Ultra 2** (September 2023)

- "Up to" 60% faster than Ultra
- Brighter screen (3000 nits)
- "Double tap" gesture using your fingers
- Fully carbon neutral (from manufacture to delivery to lifetime of use)